# Can anyone suggest how do I obtain all the values of the variable bc?

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

The variable bc is getting overwritten and I am Unable to plot all the values of the variable from the start.

I tried exporting the variable to a csv file but that didn't work.
I'm trying to detect a red, green, blue object and plot its coordinates versus time in matlab.

```
a = imaqhwinfo;
[camera_name, camera_id, format] = getCameraInfo(a);


% Capture the video frames using the videoinput function
% You have to replace the resolution & your installed adaptor name.
vid = videoinput(camera_name, camera_id, format);

% Set the properties of the video object
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorspace', 'rgb')
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 5;

%start the video aquisition here
start(vid)

% Set a loop that stop after 100 frames of aquisition
while(vid.FramesAcquired<=100)

    % Get the snapshot of the current frame
    data = getsnapshot(vid);

    % Now to track red objects in real time
    % we have to subtract the red component 
    % from the grayscale image to extract the red components in the image.
    diff_im = imsubtract(data(:,:,1), rgb2gray(data));
    %Use a median filter to filter out noise
    diff_im = medfilt2(diff_im, [3 3]);
    % Convert the resulting grayscale image into a binary image.
    diff_im = im2bw(diff_im,0.18);

    % Remove all those pixels less than 300px
    diff_im = bwareaopen(diff_im,300);

    % Label all the connected components in the image.
    bw = bwlabel(diff_im, 8);

    % Here we do the image blob analysis.
    % We get a set of properties for each labeled region.
    stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid');

    % Display the image
    imshow(data)

    hold on
 %   
 %   %This is a loop to bound the red objects in a rectangular box.
    for object = 1:length(stats)

        bb = stats(object).BoundingBox;
        bc = stats(object).Centroid;
        rectangle('Position',bb,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
        plot(bc(1),bc(2), '-m+')
        x = bc(1);
        y = bc(2);
        csvwrite('bcx.dat', bc(1));
        csvwrite('bcy.dat', bc(2));
        a=text(bc(1)+15,bc(2), strcat('X: ', num2str(round(bc(1))), '    Y: ', num2str(round(bc(2)))));
        set(a, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 12, 'Color', 'yellow');
   end

    hold off
end
% Both the loops end here.

% Stop the video aquisition.
stop(vid);

% Flush all the image data stored in the memory buffer.
flushdata(vid);

% Clear all variables
clear all
%sprintf('%s','That was all about Image tracking, Guess that was pretty easy :) ')
```

Comment: Instead of `csvwrite` use `dlmwrite` with `-append` option.

Comment: Could you specify a figure and use the "hold on" command? Or are you interested in saving the data as well as displaying it?